# How to change background color when colors are scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have an image which has many colors. it is scrolled down in the page. if the image color stops at center of the page automatically the thumbnail image color should change. Thumbnail image color is written in css. How to do this task?

[image]

Comment: can you add a fiddle to explain this?

Comment: i have no idea how to do this. The only thing i need is the thumbnail image color should change when the left side image is scrolled.

Comment: I will try to create a fiddle .See for my answer later

Comment: @Zword thank u Zword :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2kc44/ or [more complete](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/2kc44/1/).

I first declare an array of `positions` / `colors`.
You can simply use:

```
var colors = {
      0: "#FFFFFF",
    300: "#FF0000",
    600: "#00FF00",
    900: "#0000FF"
}
```

or with more paremeters:

```
var colors = {
      0: {c: "#FFFFFF", t: "White" },
    300: {c: "#FF0000", t: "Red"   },
    600: {c: "#00FF00", t: "Green" },
    900: {c: "#0000FF", t: "Blue"  }
}
```

This function:

```
$(window).scroll( changeBG );

function changeBG(e){
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    for (var c in colors)
        if(pos >= c) $("body").css( { backgroundColor: colors[c] } );
}
```

It's clean, and its easy to add more colors, but it could be more optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a point to start from: http://jsfiddle.net/Z47mY/ Here you can define your colors based on the scroll position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var color="#ffffff";
        var position = $(window).scrollTop() / $(window).height();
        if(position > 0.3) {
            color="#ff0000";
        }
        if(position > 0.8) {
            color="#00ff00";
        }
        $("body").css({backgroundColor: color});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From what i have understood i created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/6Kkmf/

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#colors").scroll(function(event) {
        $('.clor').each(function(){
        var s=$(this).attr('id');
        var r=s.substring(1,2);
        var calc=parseInt(r)-1;
        if($("#colors").scrollTop()>=($('.clor').height()*calc) && $("#colors").scrollTop()<($('.clor').height()*r))
        {
        var color=$('#'+s).css('backgroundColor');
        $("#preview").css({backgroundColor: color});
        }
        });
    });
});
```